# Using update trigger to update another table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have 2 tables, `tblTometadata` & `eventLogs`.

1st iteration:

- `tblTometadata` inserts new row for `TOMetadataParentJobID`
- `eventLogs` inserts new row for `dataPointValue` and specifies that this is a "`ORDERNUMBER`" and not "`JOBNUMBER`" yet.

So my data looks like this:

[image]

2nd iteration:

- Today, tomorrow or who knows when another process will UPDATE my table `tblTometadata` and add some value in column `TOMetadataJobNumber`.

This is when I want my `trigger` to run and take this new `jobnumber` and replace value in `eventLogs.dataPointValue` and set `dataPointType` to be "`JOBNUMBER`"

So far, this is what I got:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].ToMetadataJobNumberCreation
    --only if tblTometadata.TOMetadataJobNumber is updated with new jobnumber
ON [dbo].tblTometadata
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE (TOMetadataJobNumber) 
    BEGIN                       
        UPDATE eventLogs 
        SET dataPointValue = TOMetadataJobNumber, 
            dataPointType = 'JOBNUMBER'
        FROM eventLogs
        JOIN inserted ins on ins.TOMetadataParentJobID = dataPointValue
        WHERE dataPointType = 'ORDERNUMBER'; 
    END 
END
```

Comment: Yes you need to use INSERTED and DELETED tables to capture an update. DELETED shows what was in the table before. INSERTED shows what was in after. But you have a bigger problem. There might be _many_ rows updated at once. I don't understand your data model, but what you are doing is possibly incorrect. You should be able to join back to the original original table to work out if it's a JOBNUMBER or ORDERNUMBER. You shouldn't try and proliferate data through tables - you should use _joins_ to work out the state of data

Comment: Be wary - just because a column was *subject to update*, that doesn't mean that you know that its value has *changed*. `UPDATE tblTometadata SET TOMetadataJobNumber = TOMetadataJobNumber` would fire this trigger for all rows in the table, despite no actual data changing. Skip the `IF` and just make sure you have appropriate conditions in your `WHERE` clause to work out *what has changed*.